# Node / React - How to send data only to specific users using sse?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, server-sent-events

I want to send notifications to all and only those users who are following certain items. When user reports item, this triggers a notification of report to all followers of item being reported. What happens in my case:

lets say 3 people follow item xyz. I send notification 'xyz was reported' to 3 users, however, each user gets **3 times** that notification instead of 3 users 1x notification.

Do I need to establish a connection with each user seperatly by using his userId in the sse event? Or is there another better solution?

**my backend:**

```
const SSE = require("express-sse");
const sse = new SSE(["test"], { isSerialized: false, initialEvent: 'initialize sse' });
...

reportItem: async (req, res) => {
    ...report item
        await NotificationService.notifyOfItemUpdate(id, report.data);
...
}

const NotificationService = {
    notifyOfItemUpdate: async (updatedItemId, report) => {
        const item = await Item.findById({_id: updatedItemId});
        const message = NotificationService.createItemUpdateMessage(item, report);
        const followers = await User.find({following: updatedItemId});
        await NotificationService.notify(followers, message);
    },
    notify: async (followers, message) => {
        return Promise.all(followers.map(async (follower) => {
            const notification = await NotificationService.createNotification(follower._id, message);
            if (follower._id.toString() === notification.to.toString()) {
                sse.send(notification.messages[0], 'new_notification'); //[0] as sending the last message
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

**client**

```
const eventSource = new EventSource(url, {
      headers: {
          Authorization: {
             toString: function () {
                return "Bearer " + token;
          },
      },
},
});
eventSource.addEventListener('open', (e) => {
    console.log('SSE opened!');
});
eventSource.addEventListener(`new_notification${}`, (e) => {
    const notifications = JSON.parse(e.data);
    dispatch({type: 'STREAM_NOTIFICATIONS_SUCCESS', payload: notifications})
});
eventSource.addEventListener('error', (e) => {
    console.error('Error: ', e);
});
return () => {
    eventSource.close();
};
```